# Number of even degree subgraphs with given size in 3-uniform hypergraph clique

Tags: co.combinatorics, hypergraph

3-uniform hypergraph clique is a 3-uniform undirected hypergraph containing all possible hyperedges.

Even degree subgraph is a hypergraph in which all vertices have even degree.

The size of the hypergraph is the number of hyperedges in the hypergraph.

How to get an upper bound and lower bound for number of even degree subgraphs with size $\ell$ in 3-uniform hypergraph clique with $n$ vertices? I am interested in the region where $n$ is large and $\ell=O(n^{\delta})$ where $\delta\in [0,1)$

Comment: In other words, you want to estimate the number of $\ell\times n$ $\{0,1\}$-matrices such that all rows are distinct, each row sum equals 3 and each column sum is even? The obvious obstruction is that $\ell$ must be even, else such hypergraphs/matrices do not exist. I guess that for large enough even $\ell$ the asymptotics should be $2^{1-n}{{n\choose 3}\choose \ell}$.

Comment: Yes, and $\ell$ must be even. Is it possible for me to know how to get this guess of aymptotics, especially the factor $2^{1-n}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: For a random choice of $\ell$ hyperedges the events '$i$-th vertex is covered by an even number of the chosen hyperedges' are dependent for $i=1,\ldots,n$, but seem less or more independent for $i=1,\ldots,n-1$.